# Accessing nested columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame containing stock data from several finance institutions.

```
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
| Bank Ticker |  BAC                          |   C                                                     |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
| Stock Info  | Open  | High  | Low   | Close | Volume     | Open  | High  | Low   | Close | Volume     |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
| Date        |       |       |       |       |            |       |       |       |       |            |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
| 2015-12-31  | 52.07 | 52.39 | 51.75 | 51.75 | 11274831.0 | 17.01 | 17.07 | 16.83 | 16.83 | 47106760.0 |
| 2015-12-30  | 52.84 | 52.94 | 52.25 | 52.30 | 8763137.0  | 17.20 | 17.24 | 17.04 | 17.05 | 35035518.0 |
+-------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+------------+
```

The values are nested columns within the ticker (not sure if such structure exists in Python or if it's some sort of multiindex), with *Bank Ticker* and *Stock Info* being the column names.

I need to access all certain columns, like 'Close' from all institutions. I managed to achieve the result with the following for loop for obtaining the maximum close values.

```
for x in tickers:
     print(x, bank_stocks[x, 'Close'].max())

BAC 54.9
C 60.34
GS 247.92
JPM 70.08
MS 89.3
WFM 73.0
```

Since I'm not an advanced user, I was wondering if there's a better way to get the result, using pandas itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df.loc[:, (slice(None), 'Close')].droplevel(level=1, axis=1).max()
```

or

```
df.loc(axis=1)[:, 'Close'].droplevel(leve=1, axis=1).max()
```

or

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'Close']].droplevel(level=1, axis=1).max()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! All three solutions worked perfectly.